# Python 3.x: dict zip two list of the same length has different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I wanted to create a dictionary of values called ***pieces***,
the key of the given dictionary had to be the name of the piece and the item it's Unicode charachter representation.

I decided to write a list comprehension to retrieve the Unicode charachters and a list with all the names that I needed.

```
pieces = dict(zip(['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2,[chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)]))
print(pieces)

>> {'Queen': '♚', 'King': '♛', 'Tower': '♜', 'Bishop': '♝', 'Knight': '♞', 'Pawn': '♟'}
```

I inverted the parameters for the zip function and I got:

```
pieces = dict(zip([chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)],['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2))
print(pieces)

>> {'♔': 'Queen', '♕': 'King', '♖': 'Tower', '♗': 'Bishop', '♘': 'Knight', '♙': 'Pawn', '♚': 'Queen', '♛': 'King', '♜': 'Tower', '♝': 'Bishop', '♞': 'Knight', '♟': 'Pawn'}
```

I can't make sense of these outputs. At first I thought that maybe the second parameter 'leads' the size of the dictionary so I tweaked the size of my list of names and mixed the params, I had the following results:

```
pieces = dict(zip([chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)],['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']))
print(pieces)

>> {'♔': 'Queen', '♕': 'King', '♖': 'Tower', '♗': 'Bishop', '♘': 'Knight', '♙': 'Pawn'}

pieces = dict(zip(['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn'],[chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)]))
print(pieces)

>> {'♔': 'Queen', '♕': 'King', '♖': 'Tower', '♗': 'Bishop', '♘': 'Knight', '♙': 'Pawn'}
```

**Before tweaking sizes:** 
The first line of code prints 6 members of the first list with the last 6 members of the last list 
The second line of code prints all members of the first list with all members of the second list
**After tweaking sizes:** 
Both lines print the first 6 members of both lists

My question is: why?

As for my disbelief it can only be expressed with the following stament:

> 

Comment: `zip` only processes to the length of the shortest iterable that it has been passed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: you want to do a dict with keys being from `['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2` - but dict keys are unique, so it gets overwritten with newer pair

Comment: @h4z3 As I said replying at motyzk, I'm so dumb, I should've had more coffee today!

I'll save this post as my desktop image as a warn! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `dict` in python with duplicate keys, the resulting dict will have the key associated with the last value given to it:

```
>>> {1:1,1:2,1:3}
{1: 3}
```

This is a FEATURE that is incredibly useful!

The list represented by:

```
>>> [chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)]
['♔', '♕', '♖', '♗', '♘', '♙', '♚', '♛', '♜', '♝', '♞', '♟']
```

Is the WHITE pieces and then the BLACK pieces and represents 12 unique values.

With `['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2` you are not differentiating between White and Black pieces and this represents only 6 unique values.

So when you do:

```
>>> list(zip(['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2,[chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)]))
[('Queen', '♔'), ('King', '♕'), ('Tower', '♖'), ('Bishop', '♗'), ('Knight', '♘'), ('Pawn', '♙'), 
 ('Queen', '♚'), ('King', '♛'), ('Tower', '♜'), ('Bishop', '♝'), ('Knight', '♞'), ('Pawn', '♟')]
```

You can see that the dict created will have the first values given (the symbols for the white pieces) updated to represent the second values given (the black pieces.)

So you should do:

```
>>> piece_type=['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']
>>> [('White ','Black ')[i>=6]+p for i,p in enumerate(piece_type*2)]
['White Queen', 'White King', 'White Tower', 'White Bishop', 'White Knight', 'White Pawn', 
 'Black Queen', 'Black King', 'Black Tower', 'Black Bishop', 'Black Knight', 'Black Pawn']
```

(Or just have the list literal be the 12 unique values...)

And then you will get unique values representing the unique 12 pieces on a chess board.

---

You can also be LAZY and use the Python library to tell you what is what:

```
import unicodedata as ud
li=[(p,ud.name(p)) 
     for p in (chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16))]

>>> li
[('♔', 'WHITE CHESS KING'), 
 ('♕', 'WHITE CHESS QUEEN'), 
 ('♖', 'WHITE CHESS ROOK'), 
 ('♗', 'WHITE CHESS BISHOP'), 
 ('♘', 'WHITE CHESS KNIGHT'), 
 ('♙', 'WHITE CHESS PAWN'), 
 ('♚', 'BLACK CHESS KING'), 
 ('♛', 'BLACK CHESS QUEEN'), 
 ('♜', 'BLACK CHESS ROOK'), 
 ('♝', 'BLACK CHESS BISHOP'), 
 ('♞', 'BLACK CHESS KNIGHT'), 
 ('♟', 'BLACK CHESS PAWN')]
```

Which then shows that the original list literal of `['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']` has the Queen and King reversed.

Then it works as you expect both ways:

```
>>> dict((p,ud.name(p)) for p in (chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)))
{'♔': 'WHITE CHESS KING', '♕': 'WHITE CHESS QUEEN', '♖': 'WHITE CHESS ROOK', '♗': 'WHITE CHESS BISHOP', '♘': 'WHITE CHESS KNIGHT', '♙': 'WHITE CHESS PAWN', '♚': 'BLACK CHESS KING', '♛': 'BLACK CHESS QUEEN', '♜': 'BLACK CHESS ROOK', '♝': 'BLACK CHESS BISHOP', '♞': 'BLACK CHESS KNIGHT', '♟': 'BLACK CHESS PAWN'}
>>> dict((ud.name(p),p) for p in (chr(int(f'265{i:X}',16)) for i in range(4,16)))
{'WHITE CHESS KING': '♔', 'WHITE CHESS QUEEN': '♕', 'WHITE CHESS ROOK': '♖', 'WHITE CHESS BISHOP': '♗', 'WHITE CHESS KNIGHT': '♘', 'WHITE CHESS PAWN': '♙', 'BLACK CHESS KING': '♚', 'BLACK CHESS QUEEN': '♛', 'BLACK CHESS ROOK': '♜', 'BLACK CHESS BISHOP': '♝', 'BLACK CHESS KNIGHT': '♞', 'BLACK CHESS PAWN': '♟'}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dict` can only have unique keys. If you give it the same key more than once - it'd only "remember" the last value. Previous values would be overwritten.

It is worth mentioning that `zip` will get a length checking flag on Python 3.10 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/) , which will enable raising an error when lists given to `zip` - are of different sizes. I guess it can help sanity checking such cases.

Comment: If `zip` were to have different size iterables, there is always [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: This is not an issue of the two elements being different lengths at all for `zip`. `['Queen','King','Tower','Bishop','Knight','Pawn']*2` is the same 12 elements as the unicode character range. The issue is only about the 6 key values being overwritten by new values.

Comment: You are right, but as you can see in the question - Fabio considered the option their code doesn't work because of different length issues. The tip I listed can help eliminating that option early.